# How to remove date from showing in meta description

Tags: post-meta, seo

When my results show in Google for the respective keywords, in the meta description I see the date as well. Is there a way to remove the date?

Example meta description shows up as:

15 Jun 2009 ... My meta description

I use FV Simplr SEO and very pleased with it.. Would like to know if there's a hack for this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those links derek. I understand that is dependent on the theme being used. I did a bit of digging around and perhaps my previous Wp theme might be the culprit. Anyways, i've updated to a new theme and google is yet to pick up the new updates. Hopefully the date should disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent tried these yet but I was actually looking at the exact same thing the other day.

http://magstags.com/wordpress-seo/remove-date-meta-descriptions-wordpress-seo/
and
http://seo-ho.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-remove-date-from-meta.html